# Java for loop into parallel

Tags: java, parallel-processing

I am new to parallel processing and trying to learn it.  I got an assignment for my university and i have to turn a serial "barnes-hut" algorithm into a parallel one.
I've been searching and i don't seem to find anything useful.
I've figured i need to parallel with max thread number 4

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        double px = console.nextDouble();
        double py = console.nextDouble();
        double vx = console.nextDouble();
        double vy = console.nextDouble();
        double mass = console.nextDouble();
        int red = console.nextInt();
        int green = console.nextInt();
        int blue = console.nextInt();
        Color color = new Color(red, green, blue);
        bodies[i] = new Body(px, py, vx, vy, mass, color);
    }
```

Comment: Maybe he's not familiar with the term, then it's hard to search. Anyway, here's another [example](https://www.baeldung.com/java-8-parallel-streams-custom-threadpool). Works if console's `nextDouble` and `nextInt` are thread safe.

Comment: thanks i guess i was searching it wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Thing is: you are actually looking at more than just "adding some parallel" to your code.

You see, your code does:

- read multiple values from some input source
- a bit of processing
- store the final "results" within an **ordered** data structure (that array)

You can't just do the above in parallel. Because when you use more than one thread, you lose control when exactly things happen.

In your case: you lose control about the order of "reading from input". Yes, when you as the other answer suggests, you will run into your first multi-threading problem, because that other code isn't thread safe, therefore you will end up with unexpected, unpredictable outcome!

Also note: your code is really not well suited for "running in parallel". Using multiple threads only "helps" when your workload benefits from the multiple threads. Reading sequential data from one file, to end up with objects within a sequential data structure ... isn't such a workload!

Thus the **real** answer is: step back. Multi-threading is **really** complicated. You can't learn that stuff by picking "random" code, and then trying to "add parallels" to it. Pick a good book, or tutorial ... and research the topic. Look at well written examples, and then see how those are handled. Then search for assignments that are **meant** to learn about multi-threading.

One starting point: the [concurrency](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html) tutorials from oracle.

Comment: i totally agree with you but this Assignment was given to me today and its due to next week.If this was in c for example it would be much easier cause i could just use omp

Comment: @Dimitrisgs Then: talk to your peers. Then: talk to your tutor. Then: talk to your instructor. The people here lack the context of your assignment, and the content you learned in your classes. Strangers cant help you with your specific assignment. So: talk to those people that should know these things!

Comment: i already did that we even have a group in messenger of 10 people.The teacher has only talked about parallel processing in theory its the first time i'm hearing about java concurrency .

Comment: @Dimitrisgs The only thing I can say: you have to look at **all** of your algorithm. Unless I am mistaken, the part you are showing in your question is just the beginning: you read your input data, and **prepare** an array for later processing. This initial part isnt suited to be done in parallel. Rather look at the stuff that comes later.

Answer (score 2):

You can look at `IntStream` to parallel your for loop:

```
IntStream.range(0,N).parallel().forEach(i -> {
  double px = console.nextDouble();
  double py = console.nextDouble();
  double vx = console.nextDouble();
  double vy = console.nextDouble();
  double mass = console.nextDouble();
  int red = console.nextInt();
  int green = console.nextInt();
  int blue = console.nextInt();
  Color color = new Color(red, green, blue);
  bodies[i] = new Body(px, py, vx, vy, mass, color); 
});
```

Bear in mind this is just an example for the for loop to get you started. This **could** lead to the wrong results and will need modification for what you're doing.

To look at documentation on the parallel of "Barnes-Hut" check out:

https://www.cs.vu.nl/ibis/papers/nijhuis_barnes_2004.pdf

It is old and not using latest java techniques to simplify some of the parallelism but should be able to lead you down the right path

There is also a Scala project that simulates it as well:

https://github.com/tadjik1/Barnes-Hut-Simulation

Comment: thanks i will check that out and the link that deadpool provided